# Maple get's stuck at Evaluating trying to plot a function

Tags: math, plot, maple, continuous-fourier

My code:

```
restart;
a := 1/9;
b := 1/11;
c := 9/2;
w := sqrt(a*b);
n := 8*w;
alpha := a*b*c^(1/n);
omega := w;
sigma := 2*sqrt(a*b)/(a + b);
g := t -> piecewise(0 < t, a*sin(omega*t), t < 0, b*sin(alpha*t));
f := t -> a*sin(omega*t) + b*sin(alpha*t);
tau := k*`tau__*`;
`tau__*` := max(1/alpha, 1/omega);

# Compute the Fourier transforms
Fhat := fourier(f(t), t, xi);
Ghat := fourier(g(t), t, xi);

# Importing necessary package for animation and plotting
with(plots);

# Define function to plot |Fhat| and |Ghat| along with vertical lines at xi = omega and xi = alpha
PlotFunc := proc(k)
    local FhatPlot, GhatPlot, VLines;
    FhatPlot := plot(abs(subs(T=k*Ts, Fhat)), xi=0..max(alpha, omega)+1, color=red, legend="|Fhat(xi)|");
    GhatPlot := plot(abs(subs(T=k*Ts, Ghat)), xi=0..max(alpha, omega)+1, color=blue, legend="|Ghat(xi)|");
    VLines := plot([[omega, 0], [omega, 1], [alpha, 0], [alpha, 1]], color=[black, black, black, black], linestyle=[3,3,3,3]);
    display([FhatPlot, GhatPlot, VLines], axes=boxed, legend=true);
end proc;

# Animate the PlotFunc
animation := animate(PlotFunc, [k], k=1..20, frames=20);

# Display the animation
display(animation);
```

At animation line, it get's stuck Evaluating forever. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

I tried to use k = 1 in hopes to simplify the evaluation but it still got stuck at Evaluating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few mistakes.

The `fourier` command is part of the `inttrans` package. You neither loaded that package not called that command using its fully qualified name. So `Fhat` and `Ghat` are assigned only unevaluated calls to the global name `fourier`.

Also (if you were actually to use `fourier` from the `inttrans` package) the resulting expressions assigned to `Fhat` and `Ghat` depend only on `xi` and not on `T`. So after substituting `k*Ts` for `T` in those two expressions the results do not depend on `k`, and so every frame of the animation is the same.

You don't need to invoke `plots:-display`in order to merely show a constructed animation. (In fact, if you accidentally do then add the `insequence=true` option or else you'll see the frames all together, side-by-side.)

I'll leave it to you to figure out muddles with `T` and `Ts`, so that you can construct frames which vary with `k`. (Was either `T` or `Ts` intended to relate to `tau`?)

```
restart;
a,b,c := 1/9, 1/11, 9/2:
w := sqrt(a*b): n := 8*w: alpha := a*b*c^(1/n): omega := w:
sigma := 2*sqrt(a*b)/(a + b):
g := t -> piecewise(0 < t, a*sin(omega*t), t < 0, b*sin(alpha*t)):
f := t -> a*sin(omega*t) + b*sin(alpha*t):
tau := k*`tau__*`: `tau__*` := max(1/alpha, 1/omega):
Fhat := inttrans:-fourier(f(t), t, xi):
Ghat := inttrans:-fourier(g(t), t, xi):

indets([Fhat,Ghat],And(name,Not(constant)));

PlotFunc := proc(k)
    local FhatPlot, GhatPlot, VLines;
    FhatPlot := plot(abs(subs(T=k*Ts, Fhat)), xi=0..max(alpha, omega)+1,
                     color=red, legend="|Fhat(xi)|"):
    GhatPlot := plot(abs(subs(T=k*Ts, Ghat)), xi=0..max(alpha, omega)+1,
                     color=blue, legend="|Ghat(xi)|"):
    VLines := plot([[omega, 0], [omega, 1], [alpha, 0], [alpha, 1]],
                    color=[black, black, black, black], linestyle=[3,3,3,3]);
    plots:-display([FhatPlot, GhatPlot, VLines], axes=boxed);
end proc:

animation := plots:-animate(PlotFunc, [k], k=1..20, frames=20):
```

Now you need only this, to see what was assigned.

```
animation;
```

This also shows it, but is unnecessarily verbose here.

```
plots:-display(animation,insequence=true);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your comment and the code you provided helped me clear up a lot of the mistakes and helped me understand more of Maple.